# What do you call it when you have a number multiplied by 10?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

I have the following sentence:

> This number is the initial value multiplied by 10.

Context: Tabletop roleplaying games. I'm deriving a number from a statistic inherent to a character, with said number being ten times the statistic in question.

While it covers what I want to say, I'm not entirely keen on the "multiplied by 10" part, as it seems rather unwieldy. So I'm looking for a word that covers what I am trying to say here. I've considered the following:

> This number is the tenfold the initial value.

But this seems a bit archaic and a bit silly. Another reason I prefer not to use tenfold: I'm not entirely sure on how to use it correctly. Is there another way to say this?

Comment: But *tenfold* is usually used adverbially or adjectivally, not as a noun ("The tenfold"). The number will increase tenfold.  It is a tenfold increase.

Comment: Another reason I prefer not to use tenfold: I'm not entirely sure on how to use it correctly.

Comment: If it's in a game, "with an extra zero" may work: *This number is [ the initial value ] with an extra zero.*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> The <new value> is ten times the <old value>.

For example,

> The character's IQ is ten times the character's INT rating.

Comment: This is the most natural answer, although I would say your example is unnecessarily obscure.

Comment: @Théophile -- The example is based on the context the original poster provided in the comments to the original post:  character statistics for table-top role-playing games.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't noticed those comments. In that case, your example is perfect. :)

Comment: I've moved the relevant comment into the question. Interestingly the OP used the phrase, *said number being **ten times** the statistic in question*, thus answering their own question!

Answer (score 17):

It's a bit mathematical so I don't know if would work in your case, but you could say it's an "[order of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude)" higher.

> Orders of magnitude are used to make approximate comparisons. If numbers differ by 1 order of magnitude, x is about ten times different in quantity than y. If values differ by 2 orders of magnitude, they differ by a factor of about 100. Two numbers of the same order of magnitude have roughly the same scale: the larger value is less than ten times the smaller value.

So, for your example, you could say:

> This number is an order of magnitude greater than the initial value.

Comment: It's not the same thing: an order of magnitude greater does not mean multiplied by ten. For instance 17 is an order of magnitude greater than 1.

Comment: I agree with @MassimoOrtolano, and this agrees with the quote provided by Catija. However, we could improve the usage here by inserting the word "exactly", i.e. 10 is *exactly one order of magnitude* higher than 1. 17, however, is *not* exactly one order of magnitude higher than 1.

Comment: @AndyT No. 'Exactly' and 'an order of' are mutually inconsistent. 'Order of' is intended to convey imprecision.

Comment: @Catija Your own source says 'approximate'. So your answer is not correct.

Comment: @EJP - I believe you are right. Having googled ["exactly one order of magnitude"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22exactly+one+order+of+magnitude%22) there aren't many hits, and my comment above is actually 2nd on the list....!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect what you're looking for is...

> [decuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) [literally, to times by ten]

...following the same formulation as do*uble*, tri*ple*, quadr*uple*, quint*uple* etc.

So you would say

> *"this number is the initial value **decupled***

---

- You should note that while gramatically correct, this expression would not be found in normal use of British English. The normal use would be

> "timesed by ten", "times by ten" (or simply) "times ten"

Comment: What a cool word, +1!

Comment: is "timesed" standard in BE?  In AE it sounds like something a 1st grader would say.

Comment: @Kevin - More common in spoken English than written, certainly, but not something you would associate with a young speaker, probably more the opposite. A young speaker would say "times ten".

Comment: In AE, "Three times ten" is the verbal form of the mathematical expression "3 x 10". If one is expressing the operation in terms of an action verb, it would be "Three multiplied by ten." "Times" is the operator; "multiply" is the action.

Comment: It _is_ a good word, but it's important to note that this isn't a _common_ one. I'd be willing to bet that most native speakers would have no idea, and that a good fraction of those who would have a guess would only have that when the word appears in sequence with septuple, octuple, nonuple.

Comment: So uncommon that on  first sight I would mispronounce it as de-cuple, presumably it shoud be dec-youple. Strongly urge you not to use it in conversation unless you're being wilfully obscure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat obsolete phrase

> ten-fold

used as

> Their harvest increased ten-fold

I would just use

> ten times bigger

or

> increased by a factor of ten

Comment: The author states in their question that "tenfold" "seems a bit archaic and a bit silly." I'm not sure why you're mentioning it in your answer.

Answer (score -3):

Deca is the word you are looking for :) from Greek language

Comment: Deca is a root that can, in certain cases, be adapted for the purpose with an appropriate coinage. But there is no way you can use it as a standalone word in English.